Extract text part from inside a definition/command
The xstring package allows for
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\aftersometext}[1]{\IfBeginWith{#1}{some text}{\StrBehind{#1}{some text}}{}}
\begin{document}
\def\inputtext{some text was printed}
\def\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\outputtext
\end{document}

to print "was printed".
Issues:

I need \edef\outputtext, which is not possible with the given code, i.e. I need the expanded result.
I would like to not load a package to accomplish this.
This should work with pdflatex (expl3 is OK).
\inputtext can contain (expandable) macros.


\documentclass{article}

\def\aftersometext#1{%
\expandafter\xaftersometext\expanded{#1}\xaftersometext some text \xaftersometext\xxaftersometext{#1}}
\def\xaftersometext #1some text #2\xaftersometext#3\xxaftersometext#4{%
  \if$\detokenize{#1}$#2\else#4\fi
}

\begin{document}
\def\inputtext{some text was printed}
\edef\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\typeout{1 output is \meaning\outputtext}
1: \outputtext

\def\inputtext{not start some text was printed}
\edef\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\typeout{2 output is \meaning\outputtext}
2: \outputtext

\def\inputtext{text not there was printed}
\edef\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\typeout{3 output is \meaning\outputtext}
3: \outputtext

\end{document}

produces terminal output
1 output is macro:->was printed
2 output is macro:->not start some text was printed
3 output is macro:->text not there was printed

and pdf output


Marvellous! Thank you very much!

Below, \aftersometext is defined with \NewExpandableDocumentCommand. The test is performed with \str_if_eq:eeTF. The first 9 characters are obtained with \str_range:enn.
\documentclass[varwidth,border=6pt]{standalone}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \str_range:nnn { enn }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \aftersometext { m }
  {
    \str_if_eq:eeTF { \str_range:enn {#1} { 1 } { 9 } } { some~text }
      { \str_range:enn {#1} { 10 } { \str_count:e {#1} } }
      { The~argument~did~not~start~with~``some~text''. }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\def\inputtext{some text was printed}
\edef\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\meaning\outputtext\\
\outputtext\\
\def\inputtext{not some text}
\edef\outputtext{\aftersometext{\inputtext}}
\meaning\outputtext\\
\outputtext
\end{document}



Thank you, this works, but I cannot put a \message, \PackageError etc. into the "did not start"-branch (which I did not request in the question, so also upvoted).

@Stephen Thank you! No offence taken, but for example \PackageError can be placed in the false branch by using \exp_not:N \PackageError.
